# Сегментация речи

Tags: c#, matlab, сегментация

Требуется написать программу, которая будет сегментировать речевой сигнал пофонемно(определять , что это за буква не требуется), будь то аудиозапись или речевой сигнал с микро , не принципиально. Результат может отражаться на спектрограмме метками или, к примеру, разбиваться на маленькие кусочки аудио, каждий из которых будет содержать по букве, или какими-нибудь другими способами. Подскажите с чего начать и куда двигаться ?

Comment: Вам для дипломной работы это надо? Ну, то есть, такая работа несомненно будет являться очередным маленьким уродливым велосипедом, потому как над такой задачей уже успели поработать в течении нескольких лет большие и не очень коллективы разработчиков. А вы в одиночку на коленке хотите такое настругать. Может проще сразу воспользоваться готовой библиотекой для распознавания речи?

Comment: @Bulson Для дипломной) Уже написал прогу на распознавания , но меня отругали , что я занялся и сегментацией , и классификацией, а нужно лишь первое , мол оставим это на крайний случай вашу прогу , молодой человек) Сойдет даже "уродливый велосипед" , т.к. там важнее будет вода о  сегментации в целом , а велосипед будет отличным примером.

Comment: Питон сейчас активно используется в академической среде, вот нагугливается такая [библиотека](https://github.com/tyiannak/pyAudioAnalysis), исходники открыты, если очень нужен C#, можно подглядеть и переписать, ну и статьи можно найти, например [такую](https://www.degruyter.com/downloadpdf/j/comp.2017.7.issue-1/comp-2017-0001/comp-2017-0001.pdf), забавно, что в конце статьи список литературы сплошь состоит из отечественных авторов :) Для .Net  есть хорошая библиотека [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) c помощью ее можно читать звуковые файлы и работать с ними. Желаю успехов.

Comment: @Bulson большое спасибо